# How to send JSON data in XDR using the POST method

Tags: javascript, json, xdr

I want to send JSON data in XDR using the POST method. I'm able to send JSON data, however the problem is `.` (DOT) symbols are converted into `_` (underscores). Here is the code:

```
if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
    var xdr = new XDomainRequest(); 
    xdr.open("POST",Path);
    xdr.send(JSON.stringify(data) + '&ie=1');
    xdr.onerror = function() {
        alert('in error');
    };
    xdr.onload = function() {
        alert(xdr.responseText);
    }
} else {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: Path,
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: There was a problem in the server side scripting. After fixing that now its working perfectly fine.

Comment: go ahead and put that as an answer and mark it correct so that this question as a "correct" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your server side scripting is wrong.. 
this code seems to be correct....