# Is it IMPOSSIBLE to POST JSON with XDomainRequest?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, post, xdomainrequest

As I am not able to find a way to set the content-type to JSON for the data I sent via XDomainRequest,

I naturally ask:

Is it IMPOSSIBLE to POST JSON with XDomainRequest?

"[Only text/plain is supported for the request's Content-Type header](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx?PageIndex=2)"

Answer (score 1):

Looking at some other questions, I'd say this is possible.

For example: [How to send JSON data in XDR using the POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10442961/how-to-send-json-data-in-xdr-using-post-method)

Comment: How do you know whether the Server Side method is WCF Service method? -which normally rejects raw data but accepts XML or JSON

Comment: I answered your question ("Is it impossible to POST JSON with XDR?" -> No) but I guess there's some context to it. What are the specifics of your case?

Comment: I am trying to something similar and having issues with calling restful post service using xdr. Any luck with making this work? I tried following the example link given by Korijin but it is not working for me. I am making cross domain request and I get HTTP 400. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can still POST the JSON as plain text and have the server side read the POST body directly and handle it, even Content-Type is missing for the sick of IE.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

You cannot send  `content-type : application/json` in xdr. You can not even send any other custom header. 
xdr is only limited to `text/plain`

The best you can do is use `JSON.stringify()` and parse it on server side.

```
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(jsonObject))
```